# How can I enable JNI on Oracle JRE

Tags: java, java-native-interface

On **Oracle JRE 8**  running on Win 7, I get a notice that **JNI** is not enabled.  No information is available in the message, and I can't find any settings anywhere.  The code works on other platforms and uses **JNI**.

How can I enable **JNI**?

Java:

```
 java version "1.8.0_25"
 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

The error message is from the app, which is detecting the absence of JNI: see [Alloy - Can't find unsat core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29268687/alloy-cant-find-unsat-core)

Comment: Is "JNI is not enabled" the _exact_ text of the message? If not, can you please update your question?

Comment: On **Oracle JRE 7** running **what Java software** on *Win 7*?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch updated accordingly