# Alloy- How do I enable Unsat Core solvers?

Tags: alloy

I am currently trying to utilize the Unsat Core on Alloy, but my options for solvers are limited to PLingeling and Sat4J. I am also given a warning that JNI-based solvers are not available on my platform (see [Alloy Solver Options Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nG04a.png)). I am using Windows 10 with a 64 bit Java JDK.

How do I enable Alloy solvers with Unsat Core?

The comments on the post [Alloy - Can't find unsat core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29268687/alloy-cant-find-unsat-core) suggests that I need to add the native library to LD_LIBRARY_PATH. However, LD_LIBRARY_PATH is a Linux concept, and it leaves enabling JNI on Windows unclear. Is there an equivalent to LD_LIBRARY_PATH in Windows 10? If not, how do I enable JNI in order to use solvers with Unsat Core?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to run Alloy inside the Windows Subsystem for Linux. It then thinks its platform is Linux and gives access to, e.g., Minisat that supports Unsat Core. (On Debian/Ubuntu, you can install minisat with apt.)